# UISwitch not changing value

Tags: uitableview, uiswitch, uicontrol

I added a UISwitch to a UITableViewCell in code, and added a target/action. The problem is that when the UISwitch is touched, it starts to animate to the opposite value, buy then stops animating and returns to the previous value. So basically the slider will slide 75% of the way from OFF to ON, and then go back to OFF, so I can't switch it. Once it is switched, I add a section to the UITableView, and I don't know why this isn't working. Can someone tell me if there is anything wrong with my code?

Here is where I add the UISwitch:

```
self.forSaleSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(223.0f, 8.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
                [self.forSaleSwitch addTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(switchTapped:)
                             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                self.forSaleSwitch.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                self.currentAnnotation.isHouseForSale = (self.forSaleSwitch.on) ? YES : NO;

                [cell addSubview:self.forSaleSwitch];
```

And here is the action for the UISwitch:

```
- (void)switchTapped:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *switcher = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if (switcher.on)
    {
        [switcher setOn:NO animated:YES];
        self.currentAnnotation.isHouseForSale = NO;
        NSLog(@"OFF");
    }
    else
    {
        [switcher setOn:YES animated:YES];
        self.currentAnnotation.isHouseForSale = YES;
        NSLog(@"ON");
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the reloadData method you're asking the table view to refresh and reload all the cells.
If you're not storing the value of the switch somewhere and then restore it when the cell is created, then it will always return to its default state, which is NO.

Comment: I removed the reloadData method entirely, and the problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are settiing it properly ,The problem is

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

as the cell is reloaded it goes to default setting.Remove that line and the code will work fine.If you want to reload at htat time for some other purpose ,Manage the switch state by keeping it state saved in some variable and use it to set in the `cellForRowAtIndexpath`